# Skipping certain fields in subdocument when doing a multikey index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I tried doing a multikey index in MongoDB (Arrays containing subdocuments), but ended up going over the byte limit on many of the keys.

All of the subdocuments contain the same fields - is there any way to do a multikey index, skipping over the larger fields?

Something like:

```
db.foo.createIndex({"bar":1}, except for baz, bundy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all the elements are in a single array ( see [Compound indexes with MultiKey](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#compound-multikey-indexes) ) then it is perfectly legal to set an array on **all** the sub-properties you want:

```js
db.foo.insert({ "bar": [{ "foo": 1, "baz": 1, "buz": 1, "bat": 1 }] })
db.foo.ensureIndex({ "bar.foo": 1, "bar.baz": 1, "bar.buz": 1 })
```

And queries will use the index normally:

```js
db.foo.find({ "bar": { "$elemMatch": { "foo": 1, "bar": 1, "buz": 1 } } }).explain()

{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "test.foo",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "bar" : {
                            "$elemMatch" : {
                                    "$and" : [
                                            {
                                                    "baz" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 1
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "buz" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 1
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "foo" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 1
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                            "bar" : {
                                    "$elemMatch" : {
                                            "$and" : [
                                                    {
                                                            "foo" : {
                                                                    "$eq" : 1
                                                            }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                            "baz" : {
                                                                    "$eq" : 1
                                                            }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                            "buz" : {
                                                                    "$eq" : 1
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            ]
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                    "bar.foo" : 1,
                                    "bar.baz" : 1,
                                    "bar.buz" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "bar.foo_1_bar.baz_1_bar.buz_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                    "bar.foo" : [
                                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                    ],
                                    "bar.baz" : [
                                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                    ],
                                    "bar.buz" : [
                                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
            },
```

So the "indexName" there shows the index selected.

But of course no form of index creation allows you to "exclude" fields. It's "all or nothing" and of course the same byte limit applies to the total keys you can apply.

Comment: This only works if the sub-properties are directly under "bar", right? My problem is that my db has another degree of separation: "bar" -> 0,1,2...x (variable depending on "bar) -> "baz"/"foo"/etc.

Comment: @SLee Not sure why they would be, your question lacks that explaination. If you mean something like `{ "bar": [[{" foo": [{"baz": 1}] }] }` then nested arrays are not a good idea anyway, but ` "bar.foo.baz": 1 ` as a path is still valid. Also note that currently indexing on "bar" alone will result in the index being ignored anyway for specified properties of a sub-document. Only `{ "bar": [ "a", "b", "c" ] }` would be indexed as MultiKey and subsequently used on searches for values of "bar".